How to Define Circle Edges for Points in CATIA VBA?
I am working with VBA in CATIA and attempting to add points at the centers of the circle edges of a selected cylindrical face after assigning an axis line to that face. However, I'm having trouble defining the "StartEdge" and "EndEdge" references correctly. The code currently adds the points to the selected face instead of positioning them at the centers of the circle edges.
' Create a reference for the start edge
 Set referenceStart = part.CreateReferenceFromBRepName(GetBrep(cylindricalFace.Name & "StartEdge"), cylindricalFace.Parent)


' Function to construct a BRep name for a given geometric element
Public Function GetBrep(MyBRepName As String) As String
    ' Remove "Selection_" prefix from the name
    MyBRepName = Replace(MyBRepName, "Selection_", "")
    ' Get the part of the name before the closing parentheses
    MyBRepName = Left(MyBRepName, InStrRev(MyBRepName, "));"))
    ' Append necessary parameters for the BRep reference
    MyBRepName = MyBRepName & ");WithPermanentBody;WithoutBuildError;WithSelectingFeatureSupport;MFBRepVersion_CXR15)"
    ' Return the constructed BRep name
    GetBrep = MyBRepName
End Function

' Main subroutine to select a cylindrical face and create an axis line
Sub SelectCylindricalFaceAndCreateAxis()
    ' Declare necessary variables
    Dim objSel As Selection
    Dim objSelLB As Object
    Dim strReturn As String
    Dim varFilter(0) As Variant
    Dim cylindricalFace As Face
    Dim partDocument As PartDocument
    Dim part As Part
    Dim hybridBody1 As HybridBody
    Dim hybridShapeFactory1 As HybridShapeFactory
    Dim hybridShapeAxisLine1 As HybridShapeAxisLine
    Dim reference1 As Reference
    Dim strBrep As String

    ' Get the active document selection
    Set objSel = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection
    Set objSelLB = objSel
    Set partDocument = CATIA.ActiveDocument
    Set part = partDocument.Part

    ' Display a message box to instruct the user
    MsgBox "Select the first cylindrical face of the tube. Then press the finish button in the tools palette toolbar."

    ' Set the selection filter to only allow face selections
    varFilter(0) = "Face"
    objSel.Clear

    ' Prompt the user to select a cylindrical face
    strReturn = objSelLB.SelectElement3(varFilter, "Select a cylindrical face...", False, CATMultiSelTriggWhenUserValidatesSelection, False)

    ' Check if the user canceled the selection
    If strReturn <> "Cancel" Then
        ' Store the selected cylindrical face
        Set cylindricalFace = objSel.Item(1).Value 
        
        ' Create a new hybrid body for the axis line
        Set hybridBody1 = part.HybridBodies.Add()
        hybridBody1.Name = "CenterLine"

        ' Create a reference from the selected cylindrical face
        strBrep = GetBrep(cylindricalFace.Name)
        Set reference1 = part.CreateReferenceFromBRepName(strBrep, cylindricalFace.Parent)

        ' Check if the reference was created successfully
        If reference1 Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Reference could not be created. Please check the cylindrical face."
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' Create an axis line based on the cylindrical face reference
        Set hybridShapeFactory1 = part.HybridShapeFactory
        Set hybridShapeAxisLine1 = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewAxisLine(reference1)

        ' Set the axis line type (1 for default axis line)
        hybridShapeAxisLine1.AxisLineType = 1

        ' Append the axis line to the hybrid body
        hybridBody1.AppendHybridShape hybridShapeAxisLine1

        ' Declare references for start and end points
        Dim referenceStart As Reference
        Dim referenceEnd As Reference
        Dim hybridShapePointCenterStart As HybridShapePointCenter
        Dim hybridShapePointCenterEnd As HybridShapePointCenter
        
        ' Create a reference for the start edge
        Set referenceStart = part.CreateReferenceFromBRepName(GetBrep(cylindricalFace.Name & "StartEdge"), cylindricalFace.Parent)

        ' If the start reference is valid, create a center point
        If Not referenceStart Is Nothing Then
            Set hybridShapePointCenterStart = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewPointCenter(referenceStart)
            hybridBody1.AppendHybridShape hybridShapePointCenterStart
        Else
            MsgBox "Start reference could not be created."
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' Create a reference for the end edge
        Set referenceEnd = part.CreateReferenceFromBRepName(GetBrep(cylindricalFace.Name & "EndEdge"), cylindricalFace.Parent)

        ' If the end reference is valid, create a center point
        If Not referenceEnd Is Nothing Then
            Set hybridShapePointCenterEnd = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewPointCenter(referenceEnd)
            hybridBody1.AppendHybridShape hybridShapePointCenterEnd
        Else
            MsgBox "End reference could not be created."
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' Set the active object to the start center point
        part.InWorkObject = hybridShapePointCenterStart
        
        ' Update the part document to reflect changes
        partDocument.Part.Update
    Else
        MsgBox "Selection was canceled."
    End If
End Sub

I implemented a function to construct BRep names and a subroutine to select a cylindrical face and create an axis line. I tried to create references for the start and end edges of the cylindrical face using these BRep names. I expected that by correctly defining these edges, the points would be placed at the centers of the circle edges. Instead, the points are being added to the selected face, which is not the intended outcome.

Do you need only the coordinates of these points, or the circular edge of the face to create the points parametric?

I need circular edge of the face

You seem to be making this more complex than necessary.
Extract the face directly using the selected element reference
Set oExtract = oHSF.AddNewExtract(oSel.item(1).Value)

With this approach there is no need to play games with b-rep names.
Then make an axis line from the extract.
Set oAxis = oHSF.AddNewAxisLine(oPart.CreateReferenceFromObject(oExtract))

